# Transforming in combined tree

Tags: transforms, ros-kinetic, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a task of using a static ur5 manipulator to detect and point at a mobile turtlebot. I am a beginner and I'm told transforms is the solution I want. (Please comment if you disagree).

I have a ur5 and a turtlebot3 spawned into a an empty gazebo world.

I have a static transform publisher, shown below, in my launch file which I use to combine the tf trees of both robots.

```
<node pkg='tf2_ros' type='static_transform_publisher' name='ur5_turtlebot3_transform' args='0 0 0 0 0 0 1 world odom'/>
```

So the merged tf tree is as follows:
[image: image description]

The green bordered section on the right of the image is the turtlebot3 tf tree. Everything else is the ur5 tf tree.
As my static transform code shows, I attached the turtlebot tree to the ur5 tree at the world node.

Further down the ur5 tree I highlighted in red the *wrist_3_link* node which is the node of origin for my attempted transform. The destination node is the *base_footprint* node, the second and last node on the turtlebot3 side of the tree.

However, my **can_transform** attempts at return **0** (false). So as you would expect lookup_transforms errors:

```
def __init__(self):

    # declarations
    self.robot = moveit_commander.RobotCommander()
    self.scene = moveit_commander.PlanningSceneInterface()
    self.manipulator = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander('ur5_bot')

    self.tf_buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()
    self.tf_listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(self.tf_buffer)

    try:
        # transform_stamped = tf_buffer.lookup_transform('wrist_3_link', 'base_footprint', rospy.Time())
        transform_stamped = self.tf_buffer.can_transform('wrist_3_link', 'base_footprint', rospy.Time())
        rospy.loginfo(transform_stamped)
    except (tf2_ros.LookupException, tf2_ros.ConnectivityException, tf2_ros.ExtrapolationException) as e:
        rospy.logerr(e)
```

And, just to test, I tried a *can_transform* between nodes entirely on the ur5 side of the tree, i:e base_link to world, but still the result was false.

I'm not sure what I'm missing and/or doing wrong. I would appreciate some help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318078/transforming-in-combined-tree/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2019-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're 99% of the way there, there is just one detail of how transform listeners work you're missing.

You cannot create a transform listener then query it for transforms straight away, you need to give it a second or more otherwise it will fail to find a transform as in your case. To fix this you can add a one second sleep after you create the listener object then this should start working.

The reason is that the tf listeners needs to build up a buffer of tf messages before it is aware of all the transforms and is able to correctly answer tf queries.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2019-03-09**:
Thank you buddy ;-)